# EF 6.1: Abstract Base Class

Tags: entity-framework-6

Upgrading Entity Framework from 6.0.2 to 6.1 caused an Exception building my DBContext.

> The abstract type 'Test1Data' has no mapped descendants and so cannot
>   be mapped. Either remove ' Test1Data ' from the model or add one or
>   more types deriving from ' Test1Data ' to the model.

The situation is I have to classes (`Test1` and `Test2`)  in different projects but no reference between these projects and I want to have a relationship in my database :

```
Public Class Test1
   Public Property Test2 As Test2 //This is not working

End Class

 Public Class Test2
 .....
 End Class
```

To get the relationship in my database before EF 6.1 I made a class in my data layer (where I have the references to the different projects):

```
Public MustInherit Class Test1Data
 Inherits Test1

 Public Property Test2 As Test2
 End Class
```

Until now this worked for me. EF made the right relation in my database. I declared the class 'MustInherit' because I did not want to have a Discriminator column in my database.

But this is not working anymore. Can anybody please help me ?